# Extension Method from String to TextReader... how do I close the stream?

Tags: c#-4.0, extension-methods, streamreader, textreader

Is it possible to create an extension method similar to this?  How should I handle `Closing()` the stream when finished?

```
    public static TextReader ToTextReader(this string XML)
    {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(XML);
        return sr;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to; when the calling code closes the `TextReader` (as it should), the `Stream` is automatically closed as well. There's no need to close both objects individually.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't.  It's the responsibility of the caller to dipsose of the `TextReader` object and the corresponding `Stream`